# commandbutton changes its postion when shown using inline-edit shownonedit from when shown using javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 command buttons inside a div, initially display hidden.

```
<div style="width:1000px;height:50px;text-align:left;">
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" oncomplete="triggerBlurEvents();"   id="saveButton" style="display:none" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" id="cancelButton" reRender="thePageBlock" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

These buttons can be shown 
**1. on javacript function call :**

```
<script>               
  function show() {

    document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage.theForm.thePageBlock.saveButton}").style.display='block';

    document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage.theForm.thePageBlock.cancelButton}").style.display='block';

    document.getElementById("{!$Component.thePage.theForm.thePageBlock.AddMoreButton}").style.display='none';

  }
</script>

<apex:selectList value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_Competitor_Product__c}" multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="show();"  >
```

**And 2. inline-editing :**

```
<apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"   showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="AddMoreButton" />
```

In scenario 1, save and cancel button are displayed on top of another and in  scenario 2 they are shown side by side. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: You got any CSS applied for the buttons?

Comment: no, only style="display:none" is there for commandbutton, and there is style defined for the div, containing the buttons. <div style="width:1000px;height:50px;text-align:left;">